# What conversational UI or voice command frameworks work offline?

Tags: alexa, voice-recognition

Something I'm looking for is a conversational UI or voice command framework or extensible product (like Alexa) that can be used offline or without an internet connection. I haven't been able to figure out from Googling around if there are any good ones available. Any suggestions welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... I'd say [Google is working on something like that](https://9to5google.com/2016/03/11/google-accurate-offline-voice-recognition/).

Comment: I was under the impression that android had this as an option to download (but it was a couple of years ago that I remember this from)

Answer (score 6):

I've heard of two open solutions working on Raspberry Pi :

- [Jarvis (no kidding)](https://github.com/alexylem/jarvis)
- [S.A.R.A.H.](http://jpencausse.github.io/SARAH-Documentation/)

I didn't test them but I suppose you only need an Internet connection to initialize them.